# Can mold growth be removed and cleaned up in a two-story apartment building successfully?

Tags: bathroom, mold, ventilation, exhaust-fan, exhaust-vent

I live in an apartment building that has 24 units which all the bathrooms vent into the hollow walls or their neighbors bathrooms upstairs.  (so in their ceiling, the smell and moisture comes out through my floor).  All the units vent to the interior.  There are four dryers in the building which also vent to the interior.  Nothing vents to outside.  It has been this way for at least the past five years.  You can remove parts of ceilings and see the mold on the backside of the sheetrock or sticking to the framing.  You can also see the mold in all the corners of rooms down by the floor.  It looks like a really fuzzy black caterpillar coming out of the corners.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. All 24 units have to have their moisture vented outside before anything else is done; even after that it's going to be an enormous job. I'd move.

Comment: Yes the landlord owns this problem along with the building. Start looking for a healthier place to live.

Comment: I would be loading the moving truck last weekend.

Comment: I hate to say it but until all the vents are outside there is nothing you can do.